# how to parse xml with http post service

Tags: android

guys, I want to parse a xml in android which is got by HTTPPost method service. and I stored that xml in a string variable, but i don't know how to parse it. becoz it is in a string format. can any one give the example code for this?
.............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private RSSFeed getFeed(String urlToRssFeed)
{
    try
    {
        // setup the url
       URL url = new URL(urlToRssFeed);

       // create the factory
       SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
       // create a parser
       SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

       // create the reader (scanner)
       XMLReader xmlreader = parser.getXMLReader();
       // instantiate our handler
       RSSHandler theRssHandler = new RSSHandler();
       // assign our handler
       xmlreader.setContentHandler(theRssHandler);
       // get our data via the url class
       InputSource is = new InputSource(url.openStream());
       // perform the synchronous parse           
       xmlreader.parse(is);
       // get the results - should be a fully populated RSSFeed instance, or null on error
       return theRssHandler.getFeed();
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        // if we have a problem, simply return null
        return null;
    }
}
```

RSSHandler : Class utiliser to analyser the content in file XML

Answer (score 0):

```
DBF = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DB = DBF.newDocumentBuilder();
url_val = new URL("YOUR LINK");
dom = DB.parse(url_val.openConnection().getInputStream());
elt = dom.getDocumentElement();
NodeList items = elt.getElementsByTagName("YOUR Root Node");
for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
   Node item = items.item(i);
   NodeList properties = item.getChildNodes();
   for (int j = 0; j < properties.getLength(); j++) {
  Node property = properties.item(j);
  String name = property.getNodeName();
      if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Tag Name")) {   
      cityTitle =      property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();                         }}
```

Try this way to parse Your XML.